# Ruby and mathematical problems

Tags: ruby

I was trying to solve a mathematical problem:

```
37.9 - 6.05
```

Ruby gives me:

```
37.9 - 6.05
#=> 31.849999999999998
37.90 - 6.05
#=> 31.849999999999998
37.90 + 6.05
#=> 43.949999999999996
```

Why am I getting this?

Comment: Search SO for *is floating-point maths broken* and similar phrases.  In a nutshell -- you need to learn a little more about how computers do arithmetic with fractions, the Wikipedia article on *floating-point arithmetic* is a good place to start.

Comment: This is about python, but it applies to Ruby floating point as well:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, computers have a problem working with real numbers and use 
 floating point representation to deal with them. Much in the same way you can only represent 256 numbers with 8 bits for natural numbers, you can only represent a fixed amount of numbers with 64 bits for real numbers. For more details on this, read this http://floating-point-gui.de/ or google for "floating point arithmetic".

**How should i deal with that?**

- Never store currency values in floating point variables. Use `BigDecimal` or do your calculations in cents using only integer numbers.
- use `round` to round your floats to a user friendly length. Rounding errors *will* occur, especially when adding up a lot of floats.
- In SQL systems use `decimal` data type, or use integers and divide them by a constant factor in the UI (say you need 3 decimal digits, you could store `1234` as integer and display `1.234`.

Comment: ok, edited the answer to reflect that :)

Comment: So short and painful, if i become the numbers from other source (which i get a string from), my only/best way to deal with this is transforming this number to cents, do the math, then convert again from cents to decimal, right?

Comment: yes :)  But if you get a string anyway, you can also use `BigDecimal.new("1.234")`. Calculations with this class will be correct. Read more here: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html